# How can I automatically set environmental variables when files from a particular directory are executed?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I would like to set environmental variables in bash whenever I use a script in the ~/project/bash folder

currently, to run scripts in this folder, I have to run:

```
cd ~/project/bash
. ./project/bash/env.vars.sh
```

first, I would like these variables to be automatically set, preferably when either the scripts are used or the user changes to ~/project or therein.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of anything that will do something when a script is executed. The closest thing I can see to what you need is to put:

```
. ./project/bash/env.vars.sh
```

on the start of each of the scripts.

If that is an option for you, you can create a special user which would have the above line in its `~/.bashrc`, so the environment gets set up automatically on login.

Comment: so, I could add the following to a configuration script that they only have to run the first time?: if ! grep env.vars.sh ~/.bash_aliases > /dev/null;    then
 echo ". ./project/bash/env.vars.sh" >> ~/.bash_aliases
    ;fi

Comment: `~/.bash_aliases` is not a regular bash startup script (per `man bash` - INVOCATION section and also http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) - use `~/.bashrc`, but you are on the right path. Note this will set it up for them on every login, so if you are messing up with something like `PATH`, be sure to let them know, as it can give them a lot of headaches.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll use .bashrc. although the env. vars do set paths, they don't actually affect the PATH variable (they just set new ones like "PROJECTIN=~/project/in". so this should be okay?

Comment: Yep, if you don't touch anything that other users use, this should be fine. Won't hurt to let them know anyway...